# Display "Show Less" button when AJAX has no more posts to show

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have an AJAX "show more posts" script running on my WordPress page.

The only thing is when I click "show more" and reach the end, I would like for the button to change and say "show less" then close all of the AJAX that was shown.

How could I alter my current script to do that?

Below is the code

```
<div id="work" class="case-studies">
    <h2>
        Case studies
    </h2>
    <div class="case-study-squares">
     <div id="ajax-posts" class="row">
     <?php
$args = array(
  'post_type'   => 'casestudies',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
 );

$casestudies = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $casestudies->have_posts() ) :
?>


    <?php
        $postsPerPage = 4;
        $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'casestudies',
                'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
                'cat' => 0
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query($args);

        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

    ?>
 <div class="case-open-container">

  <div class="case-toggle"><?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?><h3><?php echo 
the_title(); ?></h3></div>
         </div>

     <?php
            endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
     ?>


  </div>
<?php
else :
  esc_html_e( 'No case studies posted yet!', 'text-domain' );
endif;
?>

</div>
</div>
<div id="more_posts" class="view-more">
<h3>
    View more work 
</h3><p class="down-arrow">
    &#x25BC;
    </p>
</div>
```

Below code is from my functions file

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery'), '', true ); wp_localize_script( 'custom_js', 'ajax_posts', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'noposts' => __('No older posts found', 'enzyme-communications'), ));

function more_post_ajax(){

$ppp = (isset($_POST["ppp"])) ? $_POST["ppp"] : 4;
$page = (isset($_POST['pageNumber'])) ? $_POST['pageNumber'] : 0;

header("Content-Type: text/html");

$args = array(
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'post_type' => 'casestudies',
    'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
    'cat' => 0,
    'paged'    => $page,
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

$rows = get_field('repeater_field_name');
if($rows)
{ $image = get_sub_field('image'); }

$out = '';

if ($loop -> have_posts()) :  while ($loop -> have_posts()) : $loop -> . 
   the_post();
    $out .= ' <div class="case-more-container">

  <div class="case-more-toggle"><img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url().'"> . 
  <h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3></div>

 </div>

    ';


endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
die($out);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
```

Below is the custom.js that also relates to this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var ppp = 4; // Post per page
var cat = 0;
var pageNumber = 1;


function load_posts(){
pageNumber++;
var str = '&cat=' + cat + '&pageNumber=' + pageNumber + '&ppp=' + ppp + 
'&action=more_post_ajax';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    url: ajax_posts.ajaxurl,
    data: str,
    success: function(data){
        var $data = $(data);
        if($data.length){
            $("#ajax-posts").append($data);
            $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",false);
        } else{
            $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true);
        }
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
    }

});
return false;
}

$("#more_posts").on("click",function(){ // When btn is pressed.
$("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
load_posts();
});
    });
```

Really appreciate any help given in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

**I hope this would help you!**

Try this out

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var ppp = 4; // Post per page
var cat = 0;
var pageNumber = 1;
$("#more_posts").text("Show More");    

function load_posts(){
pageNumber++;
var str = '&cat=' + cat + '&pageNumber=' + pageNumber + '&ppp=' + ppp + 
'&action=more_post_ajax';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    url: ajax_posts.ajaxurl,
    data: str,
    success: function(data){
        var $data = $(data);
        if($data.length){
            $("#ajax-posts").append("<div id='ajax-posts-'" + pageNumber + ">" + $data + "</div>");
            $("#more_posts").text("Show More");
            $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",false);
        } else{
            //If there are no more posts
            $("#more_posts").text("Show Less");
            $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true);
        }
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
    }

});
return false;
}

function less_posts(){
    $("#ajax-posts-" + pageNumber).remove();
    pageNumber--;
}

$("#more_posts").on("click",function(){ // When btn is pressed.
$("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
       if($("#more_posts").text == "Show More")
       {
            load_posts();
       }
       else if($("#more_posts").text == "Show Less")
       {
            less_posts();
       }
 });
 });
```

Thank you ;)

Comment: Hmm thanks for trying but it didn't seem to work... This is meant to go in the custom.js file right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, How your code works , but my script helps to change the text.

check this and try with your code, hope this will help you.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#more_posts").on("click",function(){ // When btn is pressed.
jQuery(this).toggleClass("less_show");
if(jQuery(this).hasClass("less_show")){
        jQuery("#more_posts h3").text('View less work ');
    }
    else{
        jQuery("#more_posts h3").text('View more work ');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this however this only changes the text, where I also need it to display less posts when clicked